# Wireless card not found on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I'm trying to setup Ubuntu on an old PC.

I ran `lspci` in order to get details on the wireless card installed:

```
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88w8335 [Libertas] 802.11b/g Wireless (rev 03)
```

Does anyone know where I can get drivers for this card/chip? How do I install them?

I'm sure the card is working because I just formatted on top of Windows XP, where everything had been working well.

Comment: Duplicate has been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very helpful link, I used something called ndiswrapper to help me solve my issue.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper